# Django not serving static files in production

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

**settings.py:**

```
DEBUG = False

STATIC_ROOT = '/opt/app/statics/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/statics/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'statics'),)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
import settings

if settings.DEBUG == True:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/app**

```
server {
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

    access_log on;

    location /statics/ {
        alias /opt/app/statics/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app is exactly the same as in sites-available**
Folder with static files has been granted with highest possible privileges ( chmod 777 ).

Whenever I try to run the server with command:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 example.wsgi:application
```

It actually runs the server, but do not redirect correctly to static files

Comment: are you getting not found? or anything else?

Comment: Did you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: Yes, I've run collectstatic.
Errors: Not Found

The requested URL /statics/css/bootstrap.css was not found on this server.

Comment: Please make sure you restart the nginx after `collectstatic`

Comment: Yes, I've restarted it

Answer (score 0):

use this please:

```
root /opt/app/statics/;
```

instead:

```
alias /opt/app/statics/;
```

Comment: I've used your recommendations, but the problem still occurs

Comment: after changing your nginx files restart nginx

Comment: Still nothing : \

Answer (score 0):

if your config with root is like this,

```
    location /static/ {
            root /opt/app/statics/;
    }
```

In this case the final path that Nginx will derive will be

```
/opt/app/statics/statics
```

This is going to return 404 since there is no **statics/** within **statics/**

This is because the location part is appended to the path specified in the root. Hence, with root, the correct way is

```
location /static/ {
    root /opt/app/;
}
```

Comment: Dear Sir,

After changing it, I am still experiencing a 404 error. 
Anyway, is there a possibility of logging errors of files that have not been found by nginx?

Comment: Also have experienced following error:
2018/04/16 15:21:40 [warn] 9042#9042: conflicting server name "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored